# how to install KDE icon theme in ubuntu? (ROSA Icons)

Tags: unity, icons, kde, customization

I recently got the great ROSA icon theme from the ROSA repo, I extracted the archive and put it into the .icons folder, under KDE I can select the icons no problem, but under unity using gnome tweak tool they can't be selected (nor in ubuntu tweak) so I assume that there needs to be further steps in order to use a KDE icon theme in the unity/gnome desktop?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Different **Desktop Environments** (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, LXDE, etc.) have different **Icon Themes** which cannot be used in another DE. It is possible to "migrate" icon themes from one to another but it is a long and winding road which you can of course take and even share the result with other users through sites such as [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org/)